# Scissor equivalence/congruence of two convex hulls

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, polytopes, convex-geometry

Is the convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}3\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$ scissor equivalent/congruent to the convex hull of $\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$?

The background for this is Hilbert's Third Problem.

My thoughts on these are:

The convex hull of the first set has a convex hull which is a triangle of area $1.5$, and the second set has a convex hull which is  a triangle of area $1.5$. These two triangles have the same area, so must be scissor congruent.

I'm really not sure how wrong or how right this thought process is - I'm struggling to understand my lecture notes regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following figure shows that the second triangle is scissor congruent to a $1\cdot{3\over2}$ rectangle:

[image]

I leave it to you to produce a scissor congruence of the first triangle with a $1\cdot{3\over2}$ rectangle. The two figures taken together then show that the two given triangles are scissor equivalent.

Comment: This is a lovely image! What did you use to make it?

Comment: I'm using the graphics program "Canvas" since 1995 or so.

Comment: It's very neat and very tidy, thanks very much for the answer and the program reference!